# Ionic - Populate an ion-list when button is clicked

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have an ionic list. I want to bind data to the list when a button is clicked.

```
 $scope.searchY = function(){$scope.youtubeParam = {
  key: 'myKey',
  type: 'video',
  maxResults: '10',
  part: 'id,snippet',
  q:  $scope.searchKey ,
  order: 'date',};

$http.get('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search', {params:$scope.youtubeParam}).success(function(response){
$scope.myVideos = response.items;
  angular.forEach(response.items, function(child){
    console.log (child);
  });   
});
```

I put an event on my search TextBox like this.

```
 <ion-content>
    <div>
        <label class="item item-input">
            <i class="icon ion-search placeholder-icon"></i>
            <input type="search" placeholder="Search" ng-enter="searchY()" ng-model="searchKey">
        </label>
    </div>
    <!--<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9"><youtube-video  video-id="theBestVideo"></youtube-video></div>-->
    <div data-ng-controller="AppCtrl" class="list card" ng-repeat="video in myVideos">
        <div class="item item-text-wrap">
            <h2>{{video.snippet.title}}</h2>
            <p>{{video.snippet.publishedAt | limitTo: 10}}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="item item-image">
            <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9"><youtube-video class="embed-responsive-item" video-id="video.id.videoId" player-vars="playerVars"></youtube-video></div>
        </div>
        <div class="item item-divider">
            <button class="button button-outline button-block button-positive">
                Share this Video
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</ion-content>
```

When I do a search I can see that there are returned results and the `$scope.myVideos` variable is not empty. But its not getting binded with the list card. Please what am I doing wrong. Been on this for days. it works if I call the function directly without doing a search. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every controller creates a new scope, so your search box and your video list are looking at different scopes. When you modify myVideos from the scope the search box is looking at, the changes won't be reflected in the scope that the AppCtrl is looking at.

Try moving `ng-controller="AppCtrl"` to the `ion-content` tag, then when you search returns, you can modify the correct scope and the changes should be reflected in the ionic list.

Comment: Hi abhishek, I really appreciate your reply .I actually do want to update the $scope.myVidoes variable. WhenI do a search with the search box. But its throws the error $apply already in progress. So I used ttwo different list cards and set another variable while I nulled the other . Is there a way to update $cope variables?

Comment: Just incase this helps someone else, I simply placed my new $scope.myVidoes update in a timeout function:       `$timeout(function() {
  $scope.myVideos = response.items;
})`